# Magento 2 Override Adminhtml Widget

Tags: widget, overriding, magento2, magento2.2, uicomponents

I am trying to override following widget with Magento version 2.2.2

```
/lib/web/mage/backend/floating-header.js
```

This is what I've tried so far:
\app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
  "map": {
    "*": {
      "mage/backend/floating-header": "js/floating-header-custom",
    }
  }
};
```

And \app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\web\js\floating-header-custom.js

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/backend/floating-header'
], function($){
    $.widget('vendor.floatingHeader', $.mage.floatingHeader, {
    _create: function () {
        alert("Success!");
    }
    });
    return $.vendor.floatingHeader;
});
```

But it doesn't work. I also check the Network tab for new js but it doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "mage/backend/floating-header" use "floatingHeader".

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "floatingHeader": "js/floating-header"
        }
    }
};
```